# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column '(valor)' in 'where clause' al realizar una consulta

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Al momento de querer realizar una consulta utilizando php, me aparece el error (Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'D0095' in 'where clause').

El valor 'D0095' es el valor mandado desde la pantalla, pero el codigo confunde las letras con una columna, ya que si solo coloco solo 0095, si devuelve un valor;

Modelo

```
public function BuscarCliente($busqueda) {
    $this->db->select('codigoclien, nombreclien, contraclien, direccionclien, direccioncobroclien,
     fechacontratoclien , duiclien,genero.genero,genero.Idgenero, lugarcobroclien, fechaRegistro,estatus.estatus,estatus.Idestatus,
      vendedor.codigoven,vendedor.nombreven,departamento.Iddepartamento,departamento.departamenton, municipio.Idmunicipio,municipio.municipio,
      telefonoclien, fechanacimientoclien, cobrador.nombrecob,cobrador.codigocob, comentariosclien');
    $this->db->from('cliente');
    $this->db->where("codigoclien={$busqueda['codigoclien']}");
    $this->db->join('genero'
            , 'cliente.Idgenero=genero.Idgenero');
    $this->db->join('vendedor'
            , 'cliente.Idvendedor=vendedor.codigoven');
    $this->db->join('estatus'
            ,'cliente.idestatus=estatus.idestatus');
    $this->db->join('departamento'
            , 'cliente.Iddepartamento=departamento.Iddepartamento');
    $this->db->join('municipio'
              , 'cliente.Idmunicipio=municipio.Idmunicipio');
    $this->db->join('cobrador'
              , 'cliente.Idcobrador=cobrador.codigocob');
    $consulta = $this->db->get();
    $resultado = $consulta->result();
    if ($resultado == null) {
        $resultado = 'No existe este codigo de cliente';
    }
    return $resultado;
}
```

Y el error que me muestra despues de realizar la consulta es este

```
Error Number: 1054 
Unknown column 'D0095' in 'where clause'
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Intenta extraer el valor primero y después enviarlo en el where entre comillas

```
$campo = $busqueda['codigoclien'];
$this->db->where("codigoclien='$campo'");
```

También puedes imprimir el valor de esa variable para saber como la está recibiendo y ya de ultimas imprimir el query antes del `$this->db->get();`

```
$this->db->getLastQuery();
```

Comment: Excelente, me resulto extraer el campo.